# Why is this value of variable not returning using the return statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Iam calling the Ajax function

```
function validateemp(){
var exists="";
$.ajax({
  url: "emp.php",
  async: false,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {'param1': $("#param1").val(), 'empno': $("#empno").val()},
  success: function (data) {
    exists = data.status;
  }
});
alert("exists==>"+exists);
return exists;
}
```

Iam Not able to return the value of "exists" value .Iam able to get the exact value of "exists" whether it is true or false.Due to this value not returning true or false Iam not able to build the prompt .if i return explicitly  true or false iam able to build the prompt .What iam Doing wrong

Comment: It could be that your JSON is malformed. Make sure that your JSON is properly formatted.

Comment: What is the value you're getting? What do you mean by exact value?

Comment: @karim:How can i correct the Above function .How can i return the value correctly .this is what my JSON produces {"status":"false"}

Comment: @casablanca:The exact value is "true" or "false" based on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question and comments correctly, your JSON output contains a string whereas you want to return a boolean. If so, then something like this should work:

```
success: function (data) {
    exists = data.status === "true";
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 1 second, was just typing this :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to structure that piece of code would be to invoke an event on the success of the request and pass the parameter in that event. My guess is that it's not necessarily waiting for the AJAX request to finish or that the pointer is being lost.

Restructuring it would be much more beneficial anyway.